# Impact or an impact

Tags: articles

I  used "any" in sentence 1 but as the dictionary says "impact" can be either countable or uncountable I don't understand when to use it as a countable noun and when as an uncountable noun.
If I change the sentence 1 and say "she believes it has an important impact/important impact on the environment" should I use it with the indefinite article?

1. "Carbon dioxide doesn't have any/some significant impact on global temperatures

Comment: "She believes it has an important impact on the environment" is correct.

Comment: @Peter, If I removed "an" and used it in a general sense would it be wrong?

Comment: I mean in the same way as *effect*. With or without the article Had an effect = had one/a particular (countable/specific) effect

had any effect = had any degree of (uncountable/abstract) effect